# Where to place images in a full stack app

Tags: reactjs, image

I am building a full stack app with React and Nodejs. I placed my data folder with images in the src subfolder within the client folder (my react app). Am I doing wrong? Should I place the data folder in the server side instead created with nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

For security and good practices, data and images must be stored on the server side.